# Error connecting to samba share

Tags: samba, raspbian, smb

I am running a `samba` server on a Raspbian 11 device and I'm trying to connect to it from an Ubuntu 20 device.

When I open the file manager, I can see the samba share but when I try to access to it (using the login information of the user `homeassistant`), I keep getting prompted to enter the credentials as if they were wrong.

In the log of the samba server, I only see the following message:

```
[2023/05/16 19:54:06.537441,  0] ../../lib/param loadparm.c:1918(lpcfg_do_service_parameter)
  Global parameter security found in service section!
```

This is the result of `testparm`:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Global parameter security found in service section!
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
```

This is the content of `smb.conf`:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    unix password sync = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[home-assistant]
    comment = Home-assistant configuration
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0700
    force user = homeassistant
    path = /home/homeassistant
    read only = No
    valid users = homeassistant
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't see any "service section" in the configuration file.

Comment: I was able to login to the samba share by issuing smbpasswd -a homeassistant and entering a password. Why doesn't it sync with unix password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 'security = user' in your share 'home-assistant' (a share is a 'service'), it isn't allowed and should only be in 'global'.

There are two types of users on a Samba machine, the local Unix users and the Samba users, the Samba users are not created automatically, you have to do it with 'smbpasswd -a username'. Once a user is created, Samba will keep the passwords in sync if 'user password sync = yes' is set.